# Active Inactive button in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeIgniter and ajax. So i am making a admin panel where admin can perform crud operation on clients table and also he can make client active or inactive. When the admin clicks on active button it automatically changes to inactive and also the status in database changes  from zero to one or vise versa.

Here I am facing difficulty in active inactive button. Because of ajax its not working properly and also throws error. I have attached the link of every page (controller, model, view, script and also the error with bootstrap in inspect element).

**Admin_controller.php**

```
   public function update_status()
     {
           $status = $this->input->post('status');
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $this->Admin_model->update_client_status($id,$status);
        }
```

**Admin_model.php**

```
      public function update_client_status($id,$status)
           {
              $data['status'] = $status;
              $this->db->where('client_id', $id);
              $this->db->update('client_info',$data);
            }
```

**Admin_view.php**

```
       $(document).on('click','.status_checks',function()
         { 
        var status = ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) ? '0' : '1'; 
        var msg = (status=='0')? 'Deactivate' : 'Activate'; 
        if(confirm("Are you sure to "+ msg))
        { 
            var current_element = $(this); 
            var id = $(current_element).attr('data');
            url = "<?php echo 
             site_url().'/Admin/Authorisation/update_status'?>"; 
                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: url, 
                  data: {"id":id,"status":status}, 
                  success: function(data) { 
                  location.reload();
            } });
         }  
         });




    //function
    function get_data(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo site_url() ?>/Admin/Authorisation/get_data',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                var html = '';
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html +='<tr>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_id+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_fname+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_lname+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_email+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_phone+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].client_country_id+'</td>'+
                                 '<td>'+data[i].password+'</td>'+

                                 '<td>'+'<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-success status_checks" data="'+data[i].status+'">Status</a>'+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data="'+data[i].client_id+'">Edit</a>'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].client_id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                '</td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                }
                $('#showdata').html(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: so what is the error u got?

Comment: First  the button is not changing from active to inactive and vise versa. With this when i inspect element its showing error in bootstrap cdn

Comment: @Payal Tripathy have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes the problem is solved. Issue was with the bootstrap cdn. The jquery version and bootstrap cdn was not compatible.